# showing onload with jquery ui dialog iframe ie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

i am looking for suggestions/workarounds or better ways to do this
This little bit of code works for FF and chrome but hideProgress does not get called in IE

```
function showPDF(url){
       $("#divId")
               .html('<div id="loading">Loading....</div>
                      <iframe id="modalIframeId" width="100%" height="100%" 
                          src='+url+' marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0"
                          scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title" 
                      onload="hideProgress();">Your browser does not support</iframe>')
               .dialog('open');
        return ;
   }
   function hideProgress(){
       $('#loading').hide();
   }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's your question?  Are you getting errors in the IE debug console?

Comment: hi no errors and i even had a console.log in the hideProgress and it displayed for FF, chrome but nothing in IE

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning the onload event handler call to #modalIframeId with the `.on()` or `.delegate()` function instead of placing it into the `<iframe>` tag you're inserting.  I'm surprised it works in FF and Chrome - most of the time, assigning an event handler like that with any dynamic piece of code doesn't work because of how jQuery interacts with the code of the page.  You may also want to experiment with having a unique id for the #modalIframeId iframe - If you were to call the showPDF() function more than once on a page, it would create elements with duplicate id's and that confuses jQuery and produces unexpected results.  in my experience, even if you remove #modalIframeId and then re-add it, it may still cause problems.  A unique id each time you create it prevents this potential problem.

Comment: so i tried 

 $( "#modalIframeId" ).live("load", function(event){
           console.log('modalIframeId onLoad');
           $('#loading').hide();
    });

and 
    $('#modalIframeId').load(function() {
           console.log('modalIframeId onLoad');
           $('#loading').hide();
    });
neither seemed to be called. BTW i thought i was safe using the ID modalIframeId since these were modal dialogs. I just noticed you mentioned .on() or .delegate() . I need to research how to use those.

Comment: I have tried a couple of things and nothing seems to work.
my function now looks like::
`function showPDF(url){
 $("#divId")
  .html('<div id="loading">Loading....</div><iframe class="myiframe" width="100%" height="100%" src='+url+' marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="auto" title="Dialog Title" >Your browser does not support</iframe>')
.dialog('open');
return ;
       }
 `
And i have tried .on .live nothing seems to work.
`$('.myiframe').on('load', function () {
               console.log('ON modalIframeId onLoad');
                $('#loading').hide();
 });
`

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer mentioned the issue here is the fact that you are attaching the event handler inline.  The functionality you're looking for can be achieved by simply breaking up your function.  I've demonstrated this in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xyctR/2/

'loaded' is logged in all browsers.

Furthermore, passing 'open' to jQuery UI's `dialog` method is unnecessary in this case.  Just call `dialog()`.
​